# SQL: Create custom format string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a 'calculated/formatted' string from a string of place holders. Something similar to YYYY/MM/DD being evaluated and displaying 2018/02/07.

What I am currently experimenting with is a table which contains Placeholders and their associated lookup values. An example of a Placeholder could be {1} and the lookup value is 'AreaCode', {2} is Month abbreviation, and {3} could be 'Count of entries in month'.

So if SQL receives a string parameter of '{1}-{2}:{3}' it needs to loop through each of the placeholders (Nth instance of { and }) and replace them with their respective lookups. 'OX5-Feb:6'.

Has anybody ever accomplished something like this or have any ideas on how best to proceed? If I've not explained myself clearly enough, please let me know.

Comment: What does the table with placeholders look like?

Comment: This seems like a typical token replacement to me but hard to know for sure without more details.